# how to scanf multiple values into a 2d array using only one command which varies with user input

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, scanf, minesweeper

I am attempting to create a minesweeper game whereby the user can choose how many mines to enter, list their co ordinates in a row x column manner at whic point they will be inserted into an array.The program should act as below. However I am unsure as to how I am going to scanf multiple co ordinates into an array. The code I have acquired thus far is available below.

```
Welcome to minesweeper!
How many mines? 3
Enter pairs:
0 0
1 1
Game Started
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

```
int number_mines;
int x;
int y;

printf("Welcome to minesweeper!\n");
printf("How many mines? ");
scanf("%d\n", &number_mines);

// TODO: Scan in the number of pairs of mines.

printf("Enter pairs:\n");
scanf("%d %d\n", &x, &y);

printf("Game Started\n");

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j< 8; j++){

        if (x == i || y == j){
            printf("2");
        }
        else{
            printf("1");
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Obviously you do that in a loop. Take C book, look at for and while loops.

Comment: I would prefer you go for conio.h and allow the user to press enter directly on the text UI wherever he wants in X,Y position, which is more creative and interesting

Comment: Unlike Fortran, C does not provide mechanisms that read multiple lots of data in a single operation.  You will have to write loops — possibly in a function — to do the job.

Comment: You want the user to enter the position of the mines??? I find that strange...